# Running Railo/Tomcat IIS6 sites on different ports

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, iis-6, railo

I am migration from ACF8 to Railo4/Tomcat on win2003 server.  I have for a long time used IIS to create multiple sites on the same domain.

```
mydomain.com  for production
mydomain.com:1001 for staging
mydomain.com:2002 for dev
mydomain.com:2003 for dev
mydomain.com:2004 for dev
```

In IIS with ACF this has always worked fine but with Railo and Tomcat it isn't working.  I tried adding

```
<Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="D:\website\prod\" />
</Host>
<Host name="mydomain.com:1001" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="D:\website\stage\" />
</Host>
<Host name="mydomain.com:2002" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="D:\website\dev1\" />
</Host>
<Host name="mydomain.com:2003" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="D:\website\dev2\" />
</Host>
<Host name="mydomain.com:2004" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="D:\website\dev3\" />
</Host>
```

But I can't seem to get the sites to com up correctly.  I don't have much experience with Apache so Tomcat is very unfamiliar and I don't seem to be able to figure this out. so any help is appreciated.

On a side note:
This install also made my OWA exchange web interface stop working which seems very odd since there is no cfml involved with OWA.  Exchange itself still works (I have hit it with outlook) but the web interface doesn't work.

Comment: You should **not** be running production, staging _and_ dev servers from the same machine, and especially not the same Tomcat instance.

Comment: Thanks but I wan't asking about best practices. This is the environment I have come into and I need to make it work

Comment: It's not a question of "best practises"; what you're aiming for is flat out wrong. You cannot have production and development in one: you're either running your live server on a development machine, or you're developing on a production machine, and both of those are wrong.

Comment: But you don't need either of these to get host:port working - use network level routing to send the requests to multiple machines (or VMs), and you can keep the existing URLs whilst fixing the many issues caused by trying to do everything on a single server. (And remember, with Railo there are no licensing issues to contend with; you can have as many instances as you like with no restrictions.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that with different ports, but if you could, you'd definitely have to add more connector elements for each port.

A better way IMO is to use different host names:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="production">

    <Host name="production" appBase="webapps">
        <Alias>mydomain.com</Alias>
        <Alias>www.mydomain.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="D:\website\prod\" />
    </Host>
    <Host name="staging" appBase="webapps">
        <Alias>staging.mydomain.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="D:\website\stage\" />
    </Host>
    <Host name="dev1" appBase="webapps">
        <Alias>dev1.mydomain.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="D:\website\dev1\" />
    </Host>

    ...
</Engine>
```

You can then of course set the hosts files to resolve staging.mydomain.com, dev1.mydomain.com etc., on your development machine instead of DNS entries.

Answer (score 0):

This would work much better if you use sub domains instead.

Dev.mydomain.com
Staging.mydomain.com
Www.mydomain.com

You can also run each site on a different railo instance using the following method which will gove you a more stable environment for running dev and live on same server.
http://www.michaels.me.uk/post.cfm/a-guide-to-running-railo-on-windows-with-helicon-zoo